# Im trying to kill a golang script on a specific process id but when i kill it it says terminated but is still running

Tags: ubuntu, go

Im trying to kill a golang script on the process id that i ran in on but when i kill it keeps running but i dont want to do pkill  because that will kill all the golang scripts running and i have multible running

Comment: Did you try with `kill -9 pid` command? By default `kill` command sends a SIGTERM signal. By using `kill -9` SIGKILL signal is sent to the process. More details can be found here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-force-kill-process-linux/

Comment: Yea i tried that it says killed but the go script keeps running

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12530), in case your script uses `go run`, your `kill` is only sent to the `go run` process that is waiting for the actual child process to finish. You should first use `go build` to compile a binary and then run that binary.